# How do I serve a Harp/nginx page from Docker?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, harp

I'm trying to run nginx and Harp in a Docker container to serve my blog.

I've found this: https://github.com/octohost/harp-nginx

When I run `sudo docker pull octohost/harp-nginx`, it downloads a bunch of files, but this is where I am stuck.

`sudo docker run -d -P octohost/harp-nginx` doesn't seem to do anything. After I run this, if I look at `sudo docker -ps -a` I can see that the container gets created, then exits 1-2 seconds later. I also don't know how to see what ports my website will be served on.

I know that there are several ways for Docker to access files on the parent OS: https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/

I want the `harp-nginx` container to mount a directory, for instance `~/my_blog/`, and have Harp compile these on the fly and serve them with nginx (on a custom port because 80 is already in use). I want to edit the markdown source in `~/my_blog/` from the parent OS, and have the changes automatically take effect in the website. However I can't figure out what to do with the octohost container linked above. How can I accomplish what I want?

Comment: `docker events` is the first thing to look at, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/events/

Comment: @user2915097 How do docker events help me with this?

Comment: docker events will "explain" why your containers exits after some seconds, so you can try to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run sudo docker pull octohost/harp-nginx, it downloads a bunch of files, but this is where I am stuck.

These bunch of files should be the docker images, which to be used to create docker container.

> sudo docker run -d -P octohost/harp-nginx doesn't seem to do anything. After I run this, if I look at sudo docker -ps -a I can see that the container gets created, then exits 1-2 seconds later. I also don't know how to see what ports my website will be served on.

Usually, you can check the logs of a container to see what is the problem, you can run `docker logs <container_id/container_name>`

Then we back to your problem, seems `octohost/harp-nginx` doesn't execute any command, so you should write your own `Dockerfile` to use the environment. From `octohost/harp-nginx`'s repo `README`, you can write a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM octohost/harp-nginx

WORKDIR /srv/www

ADD . /srv/www/
RUN harp compile

EXPOSE 80

CMD nginx
```

then you can build your own harp-nginx container by using `docker build -t my-harp-nginx .`, after build success, you can create a new container by using `docker run --name "harp-nginx" -d -p 8080:80 my-harp-nginx`

Note that here we map host 8080 port to container's 80 port, so you can access your container's port from `http://localhost:8080`

> I want the harp-nginx container to mount a directory, for instance ~/my_blog/, and have Harp compile these on the fly and serve them with nginx (on a custom port because 80 is already in use). I want to edit the markdown source in ~/my_blog/ from the parent OS, and have the changes automatically take effect in the website. However I can't figure out what to do with the octohost container linked above. How can I accomplish what I want?

I am not familiar with `harp`, so here is my understand and suggestions.

- You should run `harp compile` in the host but not container, just mount the compiled static content to nginx container and let nginx to serve it. If you do this, just use any `nginx` docker image such as [dockerfile/nginx](http://dockerfile.github.io/#/nginx), then mount your `harp` output to `/var/www/html`.
- Seems `harp` doesn't support live reload yet, so you need some extra tools to make it happen. [I am not sure about this part, just googled]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. If I understand correctly, `harp compile` is used to compile markdown into static assets once and then serve the html. But Harp is supposed to be able to compile the html [on-demand also](http://harpjs.com/): "*Harp intelligently compiles assets as the browser needs them, so it’s insanely fast. All you have to do is Save and Refresh.*" Perhaps instead of `RUN harp compile` I should use `RUN harp server`?

Comment: @Superbest yes, if you using `harp server` then it means you will use `harp` to serve all your contents and as http server instead of `nginx`. but for the performance consuming, I would like to suggest you using `nginx` to serve your site content.

Comment: Ah, so `nginx` can only serve Harp content if I `harp compile` to static HTMLs myself?

Comment: @Superbest you can follow this [issue](https://github.com/sintaxi/harp/issues/152), might helpful